# Eliminar y añadir items combobox tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

hay alguna manera de eliminar de un combobox un item? y también de poder agregar otro?

Encontré una forma que es con **clear** pero esta solo la limpia y no elimina definitivamente del combobox.

Lo otro tengo esta lista `combobox['values']=('127.0.0.1 (equipo1)','127.0.0.2 (equipo2))`

Comment: Debes hacer una pregunta a la vez. Uno de los motivos de cierre predefinidos es que la publicación incluye multiples preguntas. Respondí tu primera duda. Por favor, edita tu pregunta para quitar la segunda y hazla en una pregunta por separado. Por cierto, para la segunda pregunta te recomiendo que nos muestres que has intentado para lograr lo que buscas.

Answer (score 1):

Si accedes a la opción `values` del combobox vas a recibir una tupla con los items del combobox. La tupla es inmutable, por lo que no hay manera de agregar ni quitar items.
Sin embargo, lo que puedes hacer es convertir esa tupla a lista, hacer las modificaciones que necesites hacer y luego pasar esa lista al Combobox, cambiando los valores anteriores por los nuevos.

A continuación tienes un código de ejemplo:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

v = tk.Tk()

# Inicio un combobox con los items color, del y mar
combo = ttk.Combobox(values=["color", "del", "mar"])
combo.pack()

# Obtengo los items en forma de tupla usando combo["values"]
# convierto la tupla devuelta a una lista
valores = list(combo["values"])

# remuevo la primera ocurrencia de "mar"
valores.remove("mar")

# agrego al final de la lista la cadena "cielo"
valores.append("cielo")

# paso la nueva secuencia de valores a combo["values"]
combo["values"] = valores
```

Comment: Alternativa: [Appending values to TTK Combobox\['values'\] without reloading combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51590472/13636459)

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, pero si quiero agregar una funcion a un boton y que me elimine el item que esta seleccionado?

Comment: Me pareció que tu pregunta vendría mejor en otra pregunta, por lo que hice una autorespuesta. Perdón si hice mal. Aun así, espero que te sirva: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/524276/158880