# ¿Como puedo eliminar el item seleccionado en un combobox tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

*Nota:* El escenario presentado en esta pregunta es imaginario. Cualquier parecido con la realidad es pura coincidencia.

Hola comunidad! Me encontré con la necesidad de eliminar el ítem seleccionado en un Combobox. Estuve buscando en Google con las palabras clave "eliminar item seleccionado combobox tkinter" pero ninguna pagina dice como. Como lo puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podemos acceder a la posición del item seleccionado con el método `current`. Tkinter no ofrece una forma de eliminar un item del Combobox. Sin embargo, hay formas de lograrlo, pues lo que si podemos hacer es obtener y establecer todos sus items.

#### Forma 1: Crear una nueva tupla sin el elemento seleccionado.

En esta forma vamos a usar el unpacking operator. Más información sobre el unpacking operator aquí: [¿Qué significa (*variable) en Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/428956/qu%c3%a9-significa-variable-en-python/428961#428961)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

v = tk.Tk()

def elimina_seleccion():
        # obtenemos la posición del item seleccionado y la guardamos en sel_index
        sel_index = combobox.current()

        # obtenemos la tupla con los items y la guardamos en values
        values = combobox["values"]
        
        # Creamos una nueva tupla que toma hasta el item seleccionado, lo salta y toma el resto.
        values = (*values[:sel_index], *values[sel_index+1:])

        # Establecemos los nuevos valores
        combobox["values"] = values

combobox = ttk.Combobox(values=["color", "del", "mar"])
combobox.pack()

# con el argumento command hacemos que se llame a una función especifica al apretar el botón.
ttk.Button(text="Eliminar Selección", command=elimina_seleccion).pack()
```

#### Forma 2: Trabajar con listas

En lugar de trabajar con tuplas, podemos convertir la tupla (que es inmutable y por lo tanto no se puede eliminar nada de ella) en una lista (que es mutable por lo que si se puede eliminar elementos):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

v = tk.Tk()

def elimina_seleccion():
        # obtenemos la posición del item seleccionado y la guardamos en sel_index
        sel_index = combobox.current()

        # obtenemos la tupla con los items, la convertimos a lista y la guardamos en values
        values = list(combobox["values"])

        # eliminamos el item cuyo indice es el de la selección
        del values[sel_index]

        # Establecemos los nuevos valores
        combobox["values"] = values

combobox = ttk.Combobox(values=["color", "del", "mar"])
combobox.pack()

# con el argumento command hacemos que se llame a una función especifica al apretar el botón.
ttk.Button(text="Eliminar Selección", command=elimina_seleccion).pack()
```